# How to reload image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can I reload this image to get the new one from the server, using javascript without needing to reload the page?

```
<img src="?option=com_fcse&task=getimage&width=100&height=40&characters=5&r=<?php echo mt_rand(0, 10000000); ?>" />
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered Googling `javascript reload image`?

Comment: Yes but those examples look like they are cashing my image. probably I need to reset the rand in javascript now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
thatImgObj.src = thatImgObj.src.replace(/&r=\d+/, "&r="+ ~~(Math.random()*1e7));
```

<sub>(Of course, with a chance of 1e-7 to getting the same cachebreaker again - a timestamp might be a better option)</sub>

Comment: Yes, just something to replace that URL parameter. In this simple case you could've use some other string function as well to remove the digits from the end and append some new random ones.

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest way I think would be changing the `src` attribute in Javascript. So like: `YouImageElement.src += "&rand2"+Math.random();`

Modifying the `src` attribute would cause the reload of the image and because it has another random number set Client Side, it shouldn't be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

Added `id="img1"`

```
<img id="img1" src="?option=com_fcse&task=getimage&width=100&height=40&characters=5&r=<?php echo mt_rand(0, 10000000); ?>" />
```

JS Code:

```
var newImage = new Image();
newImage.src = document.getElementById("img1").src + "&_=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Added a cachebreaker at the end of the url